# C# WinForms RichTextBox middle mouse scrolling: prevent the arrow cursor

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, qtextcursor

In C# WinForms, I have a custom RichTextBox where I handle middle-mouse scrolling by myself. When it's done, I want to show my own cursor. I switch to this cursor in the MouseDown event, when the middle button is pressed.

```
    void richText_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle) {
            Cursor.Current = MainForm.cursors["hand_NS"];
        }
    }
```

However, the text box then instantly switches to the Windows "arrow" cursor. This seems to be part of the RichTextBox autom. behavior, either in MouseDown or in MouseMove. I can override this by constantly showing my cursor in MouseMove, but it looks flickery, as the two cursors fight each other. Can I block this automatic switch to the "arrow" cursor somehow?

EDIT: Tried setting the Cursor property:

```
 void richText_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle) {
            richText.Cursor = MainForm.cursors["hand_NS"];
            //Cursor.Current = MainForm.cursors["hand_NS"];
        }
    }
```

Restoring the I-beam cursor:

```
void richText_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle) {
        richText.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam;
        //Cursor.Current = Cursors.IBeam;
    }
```

}

Comment: It seems to me that you would need to override the default cursor.

Comment: Look at this, it gives a good example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursors.aspx

Comment: Sadly, I still can't get this to work. I found two attempts to deal with: 1) override the WM_SETCURSOR message , and 2) with Mouse.OverrideCursor (in PresentationCore), but neither works. Something in the text box REALLY wants me to see the arrow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233806/mouse-cursor-flickers-over-selected-text-how-to-prevent-this      https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.overridecursor(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work decently (virtually no flicker) by throwing at it all the artillery I could find. What's done in MouseMove (below) is also done in MouseDown.

```
    public const uint LVM_SETHOTCURSOR = 4158;
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


    void richText_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle) {
                this.TopLevelControl.Cursor = Cursors.PanNorth;
                richText.Cursor = Cursors.PanNorth;
                SendMessage(richText.Handle, LVM_SETHOTCURSOR, IntPtr.Zero, Cursors.PanNorth.Handle);
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.PanNorth;
         }
    }
```

Overriding the SETCURSOR message in the RTB control:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetCursor(IntPtr cursor);
    private const int WM_SETCURSOR = 0x20;

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == WM_SETCURSOR) {
            SetCursor(Cursors.PanNorth.Handle);
            m.Result = new IntPtr(1);
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Sources:

[ListView Cursor changing & flickering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594174/listview-cursor-changing-flickering)

[Mouse cursor flickers over selected text - how to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233806/mouse-cursor-flickers-over-selected-text-how-to-prevent-this)

Comment: Overriding `SET_CURSOR` cause the control always show a specific cursor. Also control is resetting the cursor in a `WM_TIMER` the flickering remains there.

Comment: @MrSparkly let me know how it turns out. I may use your solution. But did you base it off MSDN the link I sent or did it just come to you as a thought

Comment: @Reza Aghaei In WndProc, I use a bool flag when MMB scrolling (I left it out for clarity), so the override happens only when MMB scrolling. I did not mess with WM_TIMER and I see almost no flicker: maybe a single slight flash every few scroll operations or so.

Comment: @Halonic Your MSDN link shows how to deform a cursor in a custom draw operation. It's not what my problem was. I want to draw non-deformed cursor, it's just that the text box interferes with it. Like I said, I merged all the techniques I could find.

Comment: Ok, was wondering, because I never really changed cursors before, however, In my custom desktop screen reader I want to have a selection of cursors to choose from so I would follow what you did. Also that is a good tutorial for my Camp Nerd Series on YouTube. It seems that the simple stuff is the hard stuff, I have almost 10,000 views on How To Make A Borderless Form Maximize and Minimize. So this would be a good tutorial.

Comment: Changing a cursor over a plain, simple form isn't hard. It's just that the rich text box seems to have lots of old hard-coded stuff in it, especially related to scrolling, which we need to "fight" against.